# Data based on user role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, roles, user-roles

I have a product with array of prices. I want that based on the user group the corresponding price will be displayed.

As far i created roles that are describing these groups

1. Admin
2. UserPriceA
3. UserPriceB
4. UserPriceC

I would like somehow to get current users role.

Something like this:

```
public decimal Price {
    get
    {
        var price = Prices.First(p => p.PriceType.Name == Something.CurentUser.Role);
        return price; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a conditional statement based on the name of each role. Based on if the user is a member of the role, execute a different LINQ statement.

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
    // ...
}
else if (User.IsInRole("UserPriceA")) {
   // ...
}
else if (User.IsInRole("UserPriceB")) {
   // ...
}
else if (User.IsInRole("UserPriceC")) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it quite like that because a user can have multiple roles but you could do

```
Prices.Where( p=> Membership.GetRoles().Contains(p.PriceType.Name))
```

typing on this phone isn't fun... Sorry for the brevity